# MYSQL not accepting NOW() as a default value for a datetime field

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, default

I am attempting to set the default value of a datetime field to `NOW()` in MySQL but the MySQL error says it is invalid?

```
/* create the invoice table */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS INVOICE
(
    LINE_ID INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    INVOICE_ID INT(9) NOT NULL,
    QUANTITY INT(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    INVOICE_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    TO_DELIVER BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CUSTOMER_ID INT(9) NOT NULL,
    PRODUCT_ID INT(9) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (LINE_ID, INVOICE_ID) 
);
```

What is the correct way to set a default value for a datetime field?

Answer (score 1):

if you have  version 5.6.5, then it is possible to set a default value on a datetime column

you can do  like that

```
  INVOICE_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 0):

A `BEFORE INSERT` trigger can be used to assign values to columns, including assigning the current date and time to a DATETIME column.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER invoice_bi 
BEFORE INSERT ON invoice
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF NEW.invoice_date IS NULL THEN
      NEW.invoice_date = NOW();
   END IF;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Prior to MySQL 5.6.x, the only default values that can be assigned to `DATETIME` columns were literals. Only `TIMESTAMP` columns could be assigned a default value of current date and time. If you change the column to `TIMESTAMP` be aware of the "automatic" initialization AND update behavior. To have the column initialized and not have it updated whenever the row is changed...

```
invoice_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```